# How to update/download the application within app itself

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios9

I have developed application in Swift. Application is **enterprise application** so it will never go live on App Store.

I need to update the application within app if update is available for the application.

Right now I have done with backend and iOS side code. I have created .plist file which contains my uploaded .ipa file url and other things. [ref](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.in/2011/06/distribute-your-iphoneipad-adhoc-builds.html)

I have successfully implemented code of how can I download and update the app within app itself.

But the issue is when app start to download it stops at 60% and when I try to retry download it's shows error `Unable to Downlaod App`.

Is there any way I can implement the same idea ?

**Swift code**

```
    func getTheData() {
    let appversion = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
    var query = PFQuery(className:"AppVersion")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Parse unique key") {
        (version: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && version != nil {

            let oldVersion = version?.valueForKey("version") as! String
            println(version?.valueForKey("version"))

            if appversion == oldVersion {
                println("Same Version")
            }
            else {
                println(version)
                println("Different version")
                let url = version?.valueForKey("ipaURL") as! String
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:url)!)

            }
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**ANSWER:**

I have found the issue.The issue is with **iOS 9.0** and above only. From XCode 7 and above, you have to generate(Not manually) manifest.plist file with organizer only. When you are creating ipa file using export option in organizer you will get two options **1)Bitcode 2)generate manifest for OTA update**. You have to crete Manifest.plist file with XCode's organizer only.

Comment: Sounds ok, you're sure the link is to the correct OTA file and the IPA is correctly provisioned?

Comment: Yes I have double check the .plist and ipa download link.

Comment: Do you have enough space on the device?

Comment: Hey @Hiren i am flutter developer i need to create application that update from server same as your requirement. can i know you get success on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the app is open, I would recommend showing the user a message to update. The AlertView button action should take the user to the webpage to download the new version.

This is not ideal from what you are trying to achieve, but is a way I have done it in the past and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the provision profile when you create `Archive` that time you need to correct device which is listed into provision profile.

Before few days same issue I face and connected same device along with provision profile UDID container.

So I created R&D over that and [solve the same problem.](http://sugartin.info/2016/01/12/development-ios-apps-wireless-installation-problem-of-cant-connect-server/)